# $MSYSTEM variable in bashrc

Tags: bash, console, ps1

### NOTE

I am using Windows 7. On installing **msysgit** and **GitHub for Windows**, I found that git bash can be called from the folders. I opened up the terminal and first thing I wanted was to change how it displays in the console.

Here is what `echo $PS1` gave me:

```
\[\033]0;$MSYSTEM:\w\007 \033[32m\]\u@\h \[\033[33m\w$(__git_ps1)\033[0m\] $
```

I've been modifying my bash's `PS1` for some time now, and know most of the content there is. But I have never ever seen `$MSYSTEM` before.

Google resulted in nothing except some results about using it to set `$MSYSTEM=MINGW32` which of course isn't the case here.

So, what does `MSYSTEM` variable do? Also, when I create a file `.bashrc` and put this line there; the terminal now shows a blank-space just before my username. This is because of the empty space in this segment `\007 \033` but it was absent before. Here are the screenshots when I use a custom `.bashrc` and when I don't:

[image: Without <code>bashrc</code>]

<sub>Without `bashrc`</sub>

[image: With <code>.bashrc</code>]

<sub>With `bashrc`</sub>

I know why the newline is absent from my customized terminal; but the questions are:

- What is `$MSYSTEM`?
- Why is the first blank-space space missing in first case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sets the Window title to the value of `MSYSTEM` variable. As far as the
space, it looks like you messed up the final newline, notice carefully

```
export PS1='\[\033]0;$MSYSTEM:\w\007
\033[32m\]\u@\h \[\033[33m\w\033[0m\]
$ '
```

in the variable above each start of a new line insert a literal newline
character into the `PS1`.

[How to change the title of an xterm](http://faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/Xterm-Title.html)

Comment: And the leading blank-space?

Comment: But why is missing in the first screenshot and present in second?